# Cookies is not defined when using the js-cookie library

Tags: js-cookie

I have downloaded the  script: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie: and the method that I can access are explained here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie and  I have included in the `js-cookie.js` file in the `global.js` file where I am require all the local js files. I  cannot use external script src tags and so all my libraries are locally in my project structure and i require them in a global js file. The js-cookie file is working fine but I am having Cookies not defined in my VScode when I try to use the `Cookies.set` and `Cookies.get` method of the js-cookie library.I would appreciate any input on what might causing the problem and how to fix it.Can it also be an Eslint error or something to do with including it in gulp file? Any help would be appreciated.

I am able to set cookies by using `Cookies.set("name","value")` method and the `Cookies.get()` also works but in the VScode I get Cookies not defined linting error since I do not define it in the file with the script src tag but I include the js-cookie in a `global.js` file which loads all my js modules.Thanks in advance for your help